# Is there a web inspector available on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, development, web-inspector

To be abundantly clear, I'm looking for a web inspector (like [Chrome's](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)) that I can use ***on an iOS device like an iPad*** to debug web pages ***without a computer***.

[I'm aware that you can connect your phone to your laptop and do remote debugging](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/), but that's not what I'm asking about.

Background: I'm a web programmer thinking of ditching my MacBook Pro for the new [iPad Pro](http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/). I have my full dev environment setup on [Nitrous](http://nitrous.io), and I have a multitude of possible replacements for [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) (like [iDraw](http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/), though I've been bugging the Sketch team non-stop to announce an iOS version, as I would love to stay with Sketch if at all possible). The only thing I'm missing is a web inspector to use on the iPad itself to debug CSS & JS.

So, are there any such solutions out there for debugging web pages on iOS ***without a computer***?

Comment: I kind of think using an ipad will be slower without a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I found this app, but not sure how extensive is it compared to a traditional web inspector

Ergo Web Tools by James Finley
https://appsto.re/us/3vdC_.i

Let me know if you've found an alternative or something

Answer (score 2):

I have been using MIHTool: https://www.mihtool.com/ - It’s not quite as good as being on Chrome on a Desktop but it gets some of the job done!

I also use Inspect Browser
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inspect-browser/id1203594958?mt=8

Comment: ‪Does Inspect Browser app allow debugging JS step by step just like chrome on windows by hitting f12 and step through by hitting f10?‬If not is there any ios app that allow it without using mac or pc? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the Gear browser. It can inspect elements, view source, pickup color, full-screen snapshot, and more, and also available on both iPhone and iPad.

https://gear4.app

Answer (score -2):

You have to go to Settings - > Advanced -> Web Inspector and then turn it on and plug in your computer and inspect a webpage that you want.

Comment: The question is how to debug **without** a computer.

Comment: That said, the best way is probably with a computer, in which point the above question is the best answer. (I came here not caring about a computer, just funneled here by Google)